# Recent Modern Document Library Webpart Break Query String Placeholders in Custom Actions

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-actions, bug, modern-document-library

I am a targeted release user.
Recently, an update to Sharepoint Online modern webparts occured.  Some of the features of this release included the ability to count and sum list columns.  Apparently, the release also affects Custom Actions.

My Custom Action redirects to a url.  The Query String uses placeholders such as **{SiteUrl}** and **{SelectedListId}**.   These place holders are replaced by sharepoint automatically upon execution with the Document Library SiteUrl and Library List Guid.

This worked until the update that brought the changes above.  Now the placeholder seem to be totally ignored.  Now the query string upon execution has the string text of the place holder.(ie., the resulting url would be ....*sharepoint.com?SiteUrl={SiteUrl}*.  I expect it to be .....sharepoint.com?SiteUrl={...sharepoint.com....}

My custom action continues to work as expected on modern pages for users without targeted release turn on.  It continues to work as expected on classic pages for all users.

So - either their is a bug in this release that will likely break all custom actions, or Microsoft does not intend to allow custom actions of this type anymore.

*Is this a bug or expected behavior?*